# The client program in a simple C client/server messaging communication not working

Tags: c, client-server, qnx

I'm doing a lab assignment where we make a Server program and a Client program. Its on the QNX OS. Not sure if it runs in Linux. The outline is this:

"Write a pair of C programs msgSender.c and msgLogger.c to demonstrate Neutrino message passing between processes.

Your programs will be called from the shell as:

$ msgLogger logFileName
$ msgSender msgLogger

logFileName is the name of the log that stores the messages

The msgLogger process acts as a logger. It receives messages and writes the messages to a file.

1. msgLogger receives text-based messages of the format shown in msg.h. It must test the message header and only write message text to the logFile if the message type is MSG_DATA.
2. If MSG_DATA is received, the reply status is MSG_OK.
3. If a MSG_END is received, the server replies with a status of MSG_END and then cleans up and exits.
4. If the received message is not MSG_DATA or MSG_END, the reply status is MSG_INVALID and the message text is not logged. A warning message is logged.
5. This process advertises its presence by writing its ND PID CHID to a file named msgLogger.pid where the "msgLogger" part of the filename is taken from argv[0].
6. The logged messages are stamped with the time and the ND PID COID of the sender.

The msgSender is an interactive program that assembles and sends the text-based message.

1. Reads the name of the logger process from the command line and uses this name to build the name of the .pid file where it reads the ND PID CHID.
2. It prompts the user for the message header type and then for the text of the message.
3. It will exit if it receives a MSG_END from the server.
4. It prints a warning if MSG_INVALID is received from the server

   - Your client and server must interoperate with my client and server.
   - Validate that the server works properly with multiple concurrent clients.
   - If you flush your server's file write buffer after each logging message, you can run it in the background and use
     $ tail -f logFile 
     to view the messages as they are received.
   - Be sure to check the validity of the command-line argument.
   - Use global variables only when necessary.
     "

I've got the msgLogger fully working; here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/8AGfGZ5u

And here is the msg.h file:
http://pastebin.com/3xcBZvnH

And here is the code I have so far for msgSender:
http://pastebin.com/Buk88Kry

What the sender (client) needs to do, is let the user enter the message type using digits. The msg.h file contains the type of message numbers with MSG_DATA being 1, etc. If they enter an invalid digit, it'll ask them to try again, else it will store that digit and assign it to the amsg.m_hdr of the MESSAGE struct. amsg.m_data is the value with the message.

Then the user enters the message they want, and if they chose the digit 1 (msg_data), the server sends notification and the client prints "message successfully received", while the contents of the message are saved to the log file.

Unfortunately I'm having a bunch of problems and it's not logging the message. I have to hand in the msgSender tomorrow, and it's also dependent on my next lab. I really hope I can get some help on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the purpose of the MediaFire URLs?  They're compiled programs — for which o/s?  They're not very big.  We don't deal in binaries here; source is relevant, but binaries are not.  I think those should go.  How different is QNX from mainstream Unix?  It's a real-time O/S, isn't it?  Is there anything relevant that we need to know?

Comment: Are the `MsgReceive()`,`MsgSend()`, `MsgReply()` and `ConnectAttach()` functions provided by the system or did you write them?

Comment: @jonathanLeffer: they're all provided by the OS and are QNX specific, which means (for the OP) they won't be available in Linux or any other OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the buffer after the client writes.  If you don't close the file descriptor while writing to the file, there's no gaurentee that the buffer was flushed and the file was written.  You can ensure that all your writes sync to the file whne you want by calling fsync().